# Xamarin - How can we easily switch between applications targeting different versions of the framework

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work in a company in which we work on several projects for different clients, mostly in a .NET environment. We started making mobile apps, and so we naturally went with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms as a default choice. However, we are starting to wonder whether that was a mistake because, as we understand it, the Xamarin SDK versions (for iOS and Android) are strongly tied to the installed version of Visual Studio.

This would mean that :

- All developers on the same project **MUST** use the same version of Visual Studio
- If we want to use iOS build machines, these also **MUST** use the same toolchain version as the developers
- As a result, when we switch working on an older project that uses a different major version of Xamarin, all the team **MUST** downgrade their version of Visual Studio for developers AND build machines, or update the Xamarin version on the project which might introduce breaking changes.

This sounds very impractical to me, and I'm wondering if there's a catch somewhere that I missed. I have not found any recommendation regarding version management, and how to be able to quickly switch between projects using different version of Xamarin.

Any insight/best practice/tip on that subject would be appreciated !

Comment: I am pretty sure I have never faced it the other way around I think if you have the latest version of vs and the corresponding xCode you do not need to downgrade anything, all you need to be sure about is that you are having the same versions of VS, Xcode on the mac and the Visual studio on the windows system and everything else works fine

Comment: Must of the shops/agencies that I deal with use Windows Virtual Machine images for dealing with the way that Xamarin is installed in Windows as it is a PITA... and no, upgrading every solution/project to the latest VS/Xamarin versions is not an answer for those type of clients (and IMO one of many reasons that a lot agencies no longer use Xamarin) but I mainly blame VS on this, not Xamarin. On Mac it is really easy to maintain dozens of Xamarin/Xamarin.Android|iOS|Mac versions due to how the versioned file paths and how they are installed in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin (and AFAIK other frameworks) don't dramatically change their syntaxes/structures to the point where everything breaks. What they do instead is mark various methods/properties as "deprecated", meaning

> You may use this method/property/syntax, but we no longer support it
>   and suggest you use the latest available.

They may rarely change a method to exclude a parameter (for example), but it is usually deprecated and should bring up a warning when you compile.

As far as having to downgrade, that is entirely down to your company's management. Updates (whether for VS or Xamarin) are rolled out with **bug fixes and improvements**. When would you not want that?

If you are returning to an old project that is using, for example, Xamarin Forms 1.3 and has not been updated since, consider the following:

1. Does the work you'll be doing really need to be done on such an old project? Is starting from scratch not a viable option? If the answer is "yes" to either, you may need to...
2. Deal with the upgrade. As I mentioned previously, you'll get new features, improvements, and bug fixes in newer versions that is likely to improve your project development. If updating introduces breaking changes, either go to to 1. or update the project to the latest updates.

Fundamentally, if your company wants to maintain a program/app/software, they will have to deal with updates.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as easy. My personal experience is that Xamarin updates are *not* as smooth as you say. I personaly had unannounced code changes, and new bugs introduced by updates. Also, I don't want to update a dependency unless I have a reason to (a security fix or a new feature I want to use are good reasons, but a simple increment in the version number is useless to me)